# Launching a separate app's activity while overridding onOptionsItemSelected of that activity

Tags: android

So I am having no problem launching the activity that I want by setting up the intent, for example:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.android.settings/.wifi.WifiSettings"));
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

But the problem is that the user can click the Navigation Up button (i.e., the left arrow at the top left of the activity) to navigate backward in the settings app, but I want to disallow that functionality and have that button act the same way the hardware back button does, or even remove that button entirely if possible.

I have determined that the behavior of that button is established in the onOptionsItemSelected() method, but how can I override that in an app I have no control over? Or is there some other way to do this without authoring the entire second app myself?

Edit: I am still struggling with this. I feel like I must be severely overlooking something, because it should not be this difficult to display a separate activity and **require** that the user be unable to navigate in your launched instance of that app.

Comment: try like this and check `if (getSupportActionBar() != null){
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    }`

Comment: It seems to be ignoring that, though I may have not fully understood how you meant to implement it. Does that somehow pass to the newly started activity when put in my class that calls it? Because simply putting that before or after my above code is not working.